# Exception on starting Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Yesterday i installed the ADT 20 and updated the SDK and it was working perfectly but I don't know how, today when I created a new project and started the emulator, it just didn't start and threw this exception:--

```
[2012-10-31 12:01:24 - TicTacToe] ------------------------------
[2012-10-31 12:01:24 - TicTacToe] Android Launch!
[2012-10-31 12:01:24 - TicTacToe] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-31 12:01:24 - TicTacToe] Performing com.example.tictactoe.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-31 12:01:24 - TicTacToe] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Tester_2.1.1'
[2012-10-31 12:01:24 - TicTacToe] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Tester_2.1.1'
[2012-10-31 12:01:24 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: partition-size (2048) must be between 10MB and 2047MB
```

I don't understand why it is throwing this error. I have already set my partition size to 1024 then why is it throwing this exception?

If I run the old project, it will start the emulator but the new project won't, why?
Can you please help me out?

Comment: The solution seems to be here : http://worksato.blogspot.in/2011/01/tips.html , try translating it

Comment: reduce your emulator memory and try again.

Comment: Try to create new emulator and then run it again.

Comment: not working on creating new emulator also

Comment: Does it show the same error message?

Comment: Try to restart the adb by following commands

adb kill-server
 adb start-server

Answer (score 0):

From your exception

```
[2012-10-31 12:01:24 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: partition-size (2048) must be between 10MB and 2047MB
```

So edit your Emulator image and set Partition 1024 MB

Try 256 or less.
And set check box clear user data

Try set to:
[image]

Comment: well my sd card size was 20 mb and now i set it to 250 but is not working after that also and if i run the old project it starts the emulator but not on new project ! why is this happening ? i want to use this updated sdk and adt 20 from now on so how can i ..?

Answer (score 0):

Set Hardware > Cache Partition size Value between 10 MB to 2047 MB, it will solve your problem and see below link for more information.

[Managing AVDs with AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)

Comment: i had set the cache partition size to 66 but it is not working please help me

Comment: @KailashDabhi Restart your Eclipse or Restart Your Pc and then try.

Comment: I had tried all that but not working ... the other project which was created before i had installed the adt 20 are the one who starts the emulator but the new project not running and if i start the emulator by running the old project(the project created b4 adt20)and then run the new project then it runs . But if i close the emulator and then try to run by new project then it wont start the emulator.